# How can I replicate the ratchet and clank bolt sound?

Tags: design, sfx, reaper, game

I can't figure it out for the life of me. That godly bolt collection sound in the original Ratchet and Clank game just feels so good, even though it doesn't sound as good on its own. Can anyone help? I'm a beginner to sound design. Here is a link to the sound: https://clyp.it/up3xtor5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest dropping a box end wrench on concrete and recording that fairly close. You might have to do some tweaking afterward.